# Supporting hyperplane to a compact, convex set in Hilbert space at a given boundary point

Tags: convex-analysis

Does one always exist? I see that it is true in finite dimensions.

Comment: Do you know the geometrical form of Hahn Banach theorem?

Comment: Yes. I am not assuming that the set has interior.

Comment: What about considering the linear span of the convex which has an interior?

Comment: Did you mean "linear span of the convex hull"? Not sure I understand your idea.

Comment: I mean linear span of your initial convex set.